# Number of comparisons in insertion sort

Tags: python, insertion-sort

In this program, I want to calculate the number of data comparisons in the insertion sort, but my code is not working as I expected.

```
def insertionSort(list):
    numOfComp = 0
    for i in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j>=0:
            if value < list[j]:
                list[j+1] = list[j]
                list[j] = value
                j = j - 1
                numOfComp += 1
            if value >= list[j]:
                numOfComp += 1
                j = j - 1
            else:
                break
    print("Number of data comparisons:",numOfComp)
    print("Sorted list:",list)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working as expected"? umm this isnt even insertion sort i dont think

Comment: I can't calculate the true number of comparisons and sorting algorithm is not working truely.

Comment: this would be a good place to start:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: Actually if i delete the second if condition, my algorithm is working truely. But i have to calculate the number of comparisons also.

Comment: if you delete the second if what makes you think the number of comparisons is wrong?

Comment: Theoretically, number of comparisons = n(n-1)/2 but, when i gave a list that has length of 6 my code prints 8 to the screen.

Comment: thats just the average case ... best case is n

Comment: In any case,my code does not work as expected.

Comment: if you delete the second conditional then you have one *data* comparison per while loop iteration.  Try moving ```numOfComp += 1``` to the top of the while loop.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working true for average case.

Comment: you are implementing bubble sort, not insertion sort

Comment: This is insertion sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is

```
if value >= list[j]:
     numOfComp += 1
     j = j - 1
```

If `value >= list[j]` you can and should simply exit your while loop and stop further comarisons

Also you are repeating the comparisons twice
See the following refined code

```
def insertionSort(list):
    numOfComp = 0
    for i in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j>=0:
            if value<list[j]:
                flag=True
            else :
                flag=False
            numOfComp += 1
            if flag:
                list[j+1] = list[j]
                list[j] = value
                j = j - 1
            else:
                break
    print("Number of data comparisons:",numOfComp)
    print("Sorted list:",list)
```

Comment: Would you mind to write it's pseudo code ? I'm not familiar with python.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that loop header executed +1 more then the loop body, which we call the exit-condition, take this example:

```
S = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    S++;
}
```

The S++ runs **5 times**, however the **i < 5** runs 6 times, the last one is to check if i < 5, will find the false and exit the loop.